# Server IP Addresses

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am running Server 2003, and seem to have this problem where the server starts kicking out users after a while, especially when they log off, they cant log back in, or the printers on the metwork stop connecting and they can't print to it. When I check the server, I notice that the server has 2 IP addresses, even though it has a static IP, it seems to pick up another IP address as well, but when you go into the IPV set up, it's not there, but if you run the IP scan utility tool, it picks it up. To correct this, I either can log off the server, then log back in, and the IP disappears, or sometimes this doesn't work, and I need to restart the server, but this happens like every 2 days or so. Can anyone out there help?

Comment: How did the server get that IP (from DHCP, or automatically assigned)?

Comment: he current assigned IP to ther server is 192.168.1.1, and then the IP 192.168.1.35 appears after a period of time, what period i cannot tell you exactly, but it is roughly over a period of about 2 days or so. Abdul

Comment: What ip scan utility are you referring to? Did you run ipconfig/all? Does the card have an out of band management interface?

Comment: Using Netlab to scan the network, as an IP finder tool.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you run ipconfig/all on the server and see what ip addresses(es) it's really using. Maybe you have a stale DNS or ARP entry somewhere that is causing Netlab to report another ip address for the server.